# What is the voltage that goes through a computers power switch?

Tags: computers

I'm hooking up a microcontroller to be able to turn a bunch of computers on/off remotely. This is via the soft switch on the motherboard which doesn't carry any kind of load.

Looking at relays, the 5v one is slightly cheaper than the 12v one, both are 1A which is far overkill.

Does anyone know if I can save 5 cents by going with the 5v relay or do I have to splurge on the 12v ones?

Comment: You're mistaken, these 5V or 12V are the coil voltage. The allowed contact voltage usually is far higher. But it doesn't matter either, because the computer's power button is at 5V at max.

Comment: Which switch?  Is it the the momentary button on the front?  Is it the big clunky one on the back?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a magic packet on the network? .....much simpler if they have a network connection.

Comment: @jack Creasy Maybe OP wants the computers powered off completely. Mine for example can only be woken up from a power saving mode. user81993 You could simply measure the voltage to be sure. Google says 3.3V - 5V. Maybe this helps: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/129463/141308

Comment: @JackCreasey not an option if they crash and freeze up

Comment: @Janka oh yea, you are right. Upon looking up the data sheet, both relays are good up to 400v

Comment: @user81993. I guess I'm spoiled, I use Intel AMT which allows full control.

Comment: A voltage never goes through anything. A voltage exists across two points, and a current goes through something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For, specifically, an "ATX" flavor power supply, every one I've looked at (and, I believe [the standard they are built to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX)) is a 5 volt logic signal, pull low to turn on.

However, it's certainly possible that some more modern than the junk I work with (after it's done computing, giving it a new purpose in life) might use 3.3 volt logic (most of the supplies I've got experience with do have a 3.3V output, but the power on signal is a 5 volt signal.) There seem to be MANY revisions of the standard, more than I care to sort through.

You might also want to make use of the "power good" logic signal, depending what you are doing.

You may not need a relay at all.

Comment: See also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/129463/switch-on-computer-with-microcontroller

Answer (score 1):

The current and voltage required for an ATX power supply to turn ON are tiny; connecting multiple computers GND together, and running it to another machine (your 'master' unit), however, can be problematic.   Consider some inexpensive optoisolators (4N33, under $1) instead of relays.

Wiring in parallel with the front panel switch will make both
the switch and your electronic control simultaneously effective.